# Why would one use gradient boosting over neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, python, keras

I'm referring to a specific Kaggle set: https://www.kaggle.com/c/petfinder-adoption-prediction

There are a lot of columns, and I'm (for now) ignoring the images / videos. I'm training a standard neural network, but it gets stuck very quickly. I'm happy to post my entire Keras code if it'll be helpful.

I don't understand gradient boosting, but does it somehow stop from getting stuck?

Comment: Is the question, essentially, what is the advantage of a gradient boosted model over a neural network?

Comment: Yup. And if it’ll help my network from getting stuck

Comment: It's a seperate predictive algorithm that has very little to do with neural networks, so it certainly won't help out your neural network training.